# DropZone Implementation not working, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropzone is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropzone

I'm trying to create a div where I can drop files into it and it would be saved onto my web service. I tried doing it using dropzone following [this tutorial](https://codepedia.info/using-dropzone-js-file-image-upload-in-asp-net-webform-c/)! , but it's failing me at this part. I am using asp.net framework.

I've tried uppercasing and lowercasing the .dropzone(), and lowering the version to version 4.0.4

This is my view

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>
>
>
> <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
>     <div class="dz-default dz-message">
>         Drop image here.
>     </div>
> </div>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>
>
>         //Simple Dropzonejs
>         $("#dZUpload").Dropzone({
>             url: "Home/DropzoneFileUpload.cshtml",
>
>             addRemoveLinks: true,
>             success: function (file, response) {
>                 var imgName = response;
>                 file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
>                 console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
>             },
>             error: function (file, response) {
>                 file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
>             }
>         });
>     });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: what part is failing exactly?  are you receiving an error message?  if so, what is it?

Comment: The browser is giving me, "uncaught type error, dropzone is not a function" when I am calling ".Dropzone()"here "$("#dZUpload").Dropzone({ "

Comment: Try downloading the dropzone.js from their official [website](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation) and including it as they suggest.

Comment: Same error here, still investigating. `window.Dropzone` does not exist either. The minified script is properly loaded. Will try the unminified version.